# MultiMatch query with Nest and Field Suffix

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Using Elasticsearch I have a field with a suffix - string field with a .english suffix with an english analyser on it as shown in the following mapping

```
...
"valueString": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "english": {
             "type": "string",
             "analyzer": "english"
        }
    }
}
...
```

The following query snippet won't compile because `ValueString` has no `English` property.

```
...
sh => sh
    .Nested(n => n
        .Path(p => p.ScreenData)
            .Query(nq => nq
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Query(searchPhrase)
                    .OnFields(
                        f => f.ScreenData.First().ValueString,
                        f => f.ScreenData.First().ValueString.english)
                    .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                )
            )
        )...
```

Is there a way to strongly type the suffix at query time in NEST or do I have to use magic strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use extension method `Suffix`?

This is how you can modify your query:

```
...
.OnFields(
    f => f.ScreenData.First().ValueString,
    f => f.ScreenData.First().ValueString.Suffix("english"))
.Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, works a treat - didn't know about that - so simple when you know how :-)